# Intel PCI-E Quad Port Card passthrough

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet, intel, kvm-virtualization

Im sorry for maybe lame question, but Im starting with linux so have mercy.

I have Ryzen 2400G setup with ubuntu 18.04 and IOMMU turned on.
I added Intel Quad Port Gigabit Ethernet and I wanna use it on pfsense on KVM.

I saw a lot of posts etc about this issue but only with VGA pci-e cards and I cant make it work with my ethernet card.
If I understands it I need to unbind HW from driver and bind it to KVM.
But I dont know how to do it :(

Info about my ethernet controller:

```
    1d:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82571EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper) [8086:10bc] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: IBM 82571EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper) (4-Port 10/100/1000 Base-TX PCI Express Adapter for POWER) [1014:0368]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 60
    Memory at fe6a0000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    Memory at fe680000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    I/O ports at d020 [disabled] [size=32]
    Expansion ROM at fe660000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e

    1d:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82571EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper) [8086:10bc] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: IBM 82571EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper) (4-Port 10/100/1000 Base-TX PCI Express Adapter for POWER) [1014:0368]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 64
    Memory at fe640000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    Memory at fe620000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    I/O ports at d000 [disabled] [size=32]
    Expansion ROM at fe600000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e

    1e:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82571EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper) [8086:10bc] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: IBM 82571EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper) (4-Port 10/100/1000 Base-TX PCI Express Adapter for POWER) [1014:0368]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 65
    Memory at fe5a0000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    Memory at fe580000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    I/O ports at c020 [disabled] [size=32]
    Expansion ROM at fe560000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e

    1e:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82571EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper) [8086:10bc] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: IBM 82571EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper) (4-Port 10/100/1000 Base-TX PCI Express Adapter for POWER) [1014:0368]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 66
    Memory at fe540000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    Memory at fe520000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    I/O ports at c000 [disabled] [size=32]
    Expansion ROM at fe500000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
```

Can someone please help to achieve what I want?
If you need any more info about my system etc, just ask.

Thanks for any suggestions and answers..

Answer (score 0):

you can follow the [Ubuntu Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/libvirt.html.en#libvirt-management) on this which has an example on vfio based passthrough. With that you do not need to unbind, but instead create virtual functions on your card and then forward these *partitions* of the card to your VMs. It also has an example on the libvirt xml fragments that you can either add to your guest xml directly or as a file on its own to be used by *virsh attach-device ...*.

If instead you have no VF capable card you can still go with the unbinding of the device as you mentioned it. The forwarding part through libvirt looks just the same, but to unbinde you might take a look at examples of the [linux-KVM wiki](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/How_to_assign_devices_with_VT-d_in_KVM#Assigning_the_device) that uses the pci-stub.

If you don't want to use libvirt then [linux-KVM wiki pci](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/How_to_assign_devices_with_VT-d_in_KVM#Assigning_the_device) and [linux-KVM wiki vfio](https://www.linux-kvm.org/page/10G_NIC_performance:_VFIO_vs_virtio#Assign_the_VF_to_a_guest) also hold examples on the qemu commandline of this.